# Integrate Faddeeva function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, integration, gaussian

I came across this integration in my studies.

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|F((w_\textbf{_} - \hat{w_\textbf{_}})\tau) |^2 . d\tau$

It uses the Faddeeva function which is $F(z) = e^{-z^2}erfc(-iz)$. I am unsure how to integrate this equation since it contains this function. I searched online for quite a while but could not find any information pertaining to my problem. Can someone point me in the right direction to solve this integral?

Comment: Is it possible to replace $w_{\textbf{_}} - \hat{w_\textbf{_}}$ by $a$?

Comment: Yes it is possible, I just wrote out the statement for completeness.

Comment: After $t=a\tau$ you will get $I(a)=c/a$, where $c=I(1)$.

Comment: What is the function $I$?

Comment: $I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|F(a\tau) |^2  d\tau$